# Python Datalogger - Pyzmq and Multiprocessing

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I am attempting to make a datalogger application in python. In this program I will be using PyQt5 to display data, graphs, etc with a separate process for data acquisition and separate process for saving data.

The data coming in could be up to 100-200 kHz so I needed a fast way to pass data around between processes, hence pyzmq.

My strategy was to use pub-sub in order for the csv process and gui process to have access to the data. I've read about slow joiners and realize I need to synchronize my publishers and subscribers if I don't want either subscriber missing any messages.

Should I also include a forwarder device if I plan on being able to start and stop the data acquisition from the GUI? If so, is there a proper way to do synchronization in the forwarder (I could not find much on that)?

Any help or ideas to my program's architecture would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: These sorts of open ended advice questions aren't a great fit for Stack Overflow, so I'm going to suggest to close, but if you want to design even a rudimentary network topology then that's something concrete we can give feedback on.  Otherwise we're just working on too many assumptions and not enough understanding of your problem domain.

Comment: For data processing and parallelisation I would suggest you to look into openMPI. Otherwise ti's really hard to give you an answer without knowing exactly what you want to do. There is no universal answer to this sort of question It's always very specific to YOUR use case. If you really want performance I would suggest to do the data processing in C++ (or Rust). Python is a relatively slow language generally speaking.